# Read blocking even closing the Write ends

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, system-calls

```
int  main()
{


    int p[2];
    int p1[2];
    pipe(p);
    pipe(p1);

    int pid,status;

    char buff[10000];

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    { 
        close(p[0]);
        dup2(p[1],1);
        close(p[1]);

        char *argv[] = {"ls","-l",NULL};
        execv("/bin/ls",argv);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&status);
        pid =fork();
        if (pid ==0)
        {
            close(p[1]);
            dup2(p[0],0);
            close(p[0]);

            close(p1[0]);
            dup2(p1[1],1);
            close(p1[1]);

            char *argv[] = {"uniq",NULL};

            execv("/bin/uniq",argv);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&status);

            close(p1[1]);
            dup2(p1[0],0);
            close(p1[0]);

            char *argv[] = {"grep","^d",NULL};
            execv("/bin/grep",argv);
        }
    }
}
```

Why read is blocking  in the child(uniq process) even I have closed the ends properly (assume i have closed). Tried strace and was keeping hitting this for 3 to 4 hrs.still i am wondering why its blocking ... any help would help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not closing all your unused pipe file descriptors. For instance, in your last branch where you `exec("/bin/grep", argv)`, you're closing `p1[1]` and `dup2()`ing `p1[0]`, but you're not closing `p[0]` or `p[1]`. So when `ls` has finished writing to `uniq`, that pipe stays open because you still have dangling references to it.

You're also not checking any of your system calls for errors, which you should.

Here's a revised version (modified slightly because `grep` and `uniq` are in different locations on my system):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int p1to2[2];
    int p2to3[2];

    if ( pipe(p1to2) == -1 || pipe(p2to3) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling pipe()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t pid;

    if ( (pid = fork()) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling first fork()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        if ( close(p1to2[0]) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling close() on p1to2[0]");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if ( p1to2[1] != STDOUT_FILENO ) {
            if ( dup2(p1to2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                perror("error calling dup2() on p1to2[1]");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ( close(p1to2[1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("error calling close() on p1to2[1]");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        if ( close(p2to3[0]) == -1 || close(p2to3[1]) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling close() on p2to3");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        char *argv[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};

        if ( execv("/bin/ls", argv) == -1 ) {
            perror("couldn't execute /bin/ls");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        if ( (pid = fork()) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling second fork()");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else if ( pid == 0 ) {
            if ( close(p1to2[1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("error calling close() on p1to2[1]");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ( p1to2[0] != STDIN_FILENO ) {
                if ( dup2(p1to2[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling dup2() on p1to2[0]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                if ( close(p1to2[0]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling close() on p1to2[0]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }

            if ( close(p2to3[0]) == -1 ) {
                perror("error calling close() on p2to3[0]");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ( p2to3[1] != STDOUT_FILENO ) {
                if ( dup2(p2to3[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling dup2() on p2to3[1]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                if ( close(p2to3[1]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling close() on p2to3[1]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }

            char *argv[] = {"uniq", NULL};

            if ( execv("/usr/bin/uniq", argv) == -1 ) {
                perror("couldn't execute /usr/bin/uniq");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        } else {
            if ( close(p1to2[0]) == -1 || close(p1to2[1]) == -1 ) {
                perror("error calling close() on p1to2");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if ( close(p2to3[1]) == -1 ){
                perror("error calling close() on p2to3[1]");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if ( p2to3[0] != STDIN_FILENO ) {
                if ( dup2(p2to3[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling dup2() on p2to3[0]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                if ( close(p2to3[0]) == -1 ) {
                    perror("error calling close() on p2to3[0]");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }

            char *argv[] = {"grep", "pipes", NULL};

            if ( execv("/usr/bin/grep", argv) == -1 ) {
                perror("couldn't execute /usr/bin/grep");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and output:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ ./pipes
-rwxr-xr-x  1 paul  staff  8812 Oct 25 12:21 pipes
-rw-r--r--  1 paul  staff  3817 Oct 25 12:21 pipes.c
-rw-------  1 paul  staff   660 Oct 25 11:03 pipes.c.BAK
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

Incidentally, it's really easy to get confused when you have multiple pipes, `close()`s, `dup2()`s, and variables like `p` and `p1`, particularly when you add in the error checking you *need* to be doing. This is a prime example of where composing your program into functions can help enormously, and avoid introducing bugs just as a result of it being difficult to figure out what's going on.

Here's a suggested composition, I'd suggest the `main()` function is significantly easier to follow, to reason about, and to troubleshoot, here:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void make_pipes(int * p, ...);
pid_t fork_or_die(void);
void close_pipe_pair(int * p);
void make_std_reader(int * p);
void make_std_writer(int * p);
void execv_or_die(const char * path, char * const argv[]);

/*  Main function  */

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int p1to2[2], p2to3[2];

    make_pipes(p1to2, p2to3, NULL);

    if ( (pid = fork_or_die()) == 0 ) {
        make_std_writer(p1to2);
        close_pipe_pair(p2to3);

        char * args[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
        execv_or_die("/bin/ls", args);
    } else {
        if ( (pid = fork_or_die()) == 0 ) {
            make_std_reader(p1to2);
            make_std_writer(p2to3);

            char * args[] = {"uniq", NULL};
            execv_or_die("/usr/bin/uniq", args);
        } else {
            close_pipe_pair(p1to2);
            make_std_reader(p2to3);

            char * args[] = {"grep", "pipes", NULL};
            execv_or_die("/usr/bin/grep", args);
        }
    }
}

/*  Creates a pipe for each array in the NULL terminated arg list  */

void make_pipes(int * p, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, p);
    while ( p ) {
        if ( pipe(p) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling pipe()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        p = va_arg(ap, int *);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

/*  Calls fork() and exits on error  */

pid_t fork_or_die(void)
{
    pid_t p = fork();
    if ( p == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

/*  Closes a pipe pair and exits on error */

void close_pipe_pair(int * p)
{
    if ( close(p[0]) == -1 || close(p[1]) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling close() in close_pipe_pair()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/*  Closes the write end of a pipe and duplicates
 *  the read end into STDIN_FILENO, exiting on error  */

void make_std_reader(int * p)
{
    static const int read_end = 0;
    static const int write_end = 1;

    if ( close(p[write_end]) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling close() in make_std_reader()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( p[read_end] != STDIN_FILENO ) {
        if ( dup2(p[read_end], STDIN_FILENO) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling dup2() in make_std_reader()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ( close(p[read_end]) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling close() in make_std_reader()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

/*  Closes the read end of a pipe and duplicates
 *  the write end into STDOUT_FILENO, exiting on error  */

void make_std_writer(int * p)
{
    static const int read_end = 0;
    static const int write_end = 1;

    if ( close(p[read_end]) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling close() in make_std_writer()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( p[write_end] != STDOUT_FILENO ) {
        if ( dup2(p[write_end], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling dup2() in make_std_writer()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ( close(p[write_end]) == -1 ) {
            perror("error calling close() in make_std_writer()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

/*  Calls execv() and exits on error  */

void execv_or_die(const char * path, char * const argv[])
{
    if ( execv(path, argv) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling execv()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks paul.. Will try it n get back. Also will look into the yo suggested composition  n will follow it to make my life easy :)